# CSS child won't inherit height. Parent height in VH. Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

First question asked here. I've looked around and googled but I can't find a solution to my problem.

I have a parent (Bootstrap row) that takes up a calculated height, 100vh - 140px. This works great but I can't get it's children to take up percentage of it's parent. I have 3 divs inside. I want one to take upp 100% of it's parents height, and the other two 40% and 60%.

I've read that 'height: inherit;' should work, but it doesn't. For compatibility I've  also added max-height with the wanted percentage.

I've tried Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

CSS code:

```
// Parent
#start-page {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 140px);
}
// Children
#init-square-1 {
    height: inherit;
    max-height: 100%;
}
#init-square-2 {
    height: inherit;
    max-height: 40%;
}
#init-square-3 {
    height: inherit;
    max-height: 60%;
}
HTML:
    <section id="start-page" class="row">
        <div id="init-square-1" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
        <div id="init-square-2" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
        <div id="init-square-3" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
    </section>
```

Comment: `inherit` can’t work, if there is nothing to inherit from (and there isn’t, because the parent element doesn’t have an explicit height set.) That you are not specifying heights here, but only min-heights, might be an additional problem. I’d really recommend that you look into flexbox, that should be better suited to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and explanation! If it where up to me, I'd definitely use Flexbox instead, but I have to stick to Bootstrap on this project.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, all I needed to do was change the parents height to just

```
height: calc(100vh - 140px);
```

instead of:

```
min-height: calc(100vh - 140px);
```

So, removing 'min' from height did the trick.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`height: inherit;` does not mean that the inherits the height from the parent element but from the parent configuration, so from the div in that case. The `div` element's default height is 0, so 0 is inherited.

I'm not sure what height you want to set, but if the have to be the same height as `#start-page`, then set the height to 100%

```
height:100%;
```

Also it might be needed (not sure) to give the outer container a position:relative

```
#start-page {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 140px);
    position:relative;
}
```